# Angular2 Mvc5 sample application doesn't compile

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3. I have created a new project "Angular2 Mvc5 sample application" from the Online templates.

When I compile it I got lot of errors like:

*Error  TS2307  Cannot find module '@angular/core'.*

*Error  TS2307  Cannot find module '@angular/http'.*

*Error  TS2503  Cannot find namespace 'Models'.*

What can I do in order to compile it without these errors?

Thanks!

Below is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "Scripts/TypeLite.Net4.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you do npm install?

Comment: What version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: Do you refer at: npm install Angular2?

Comment: I'm using node.js v7.2.0.

Comment: I will assume you did npm install, can you add your tsconfig to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean with "did npm install".

Comment: What I meant npm install is that you need to install all the packages on packages.json that is required to run angular 2. You need to run this on your command line where packages.json is located, which should produce node_modules folder containing all the packages.

Comment: This is not the same as right-click package.json file in Solution Explorer and choose "Restore Packages"?

Comment: Yes, and I don't see any issue with tsconfig. Can you provide the project template link that you are using?

Comment: I have created the project from Visual Studio: File/New/Project/Online. And there I searched for Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create the project with the template you mention. I did not have any luck using "right click package.json and Restore Packages" there was an 404 not found for packages shown in the output.

So instead I did "npm install" via command line, and I was able to compile just fine.

Make sure "node_modules" exists on your directory.

Another thing to note is that the packages are outdated on the package.json.

Comment: I did "npm install" via command line and now all is good. Thanks!